# free 2d array in c

Tags: c, memory-management, multidimensional-array

I was solving some simple pointer exercises when i came across the following example:

```
void deallocate2D(int** array, int nrows) {     
 /*  deallocate each row  */
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
      free(array[i]);
 }

 /*  deallocate array of pointers  */
 free(array);     
}
```

The array is defined in main as int** array1;

Is this a correct way of deallocating memory of a 2d array or should an int*** array be passed in the function instead?
Is there a way to check that memory has been successfully deallocated?

Comment: for the vocabulary, what you handle here is not a 2D array but an array of pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. `int***` is only necessary if you intend to change the value of the pointer, which you don't need to.

There do exist tools which can check your memory allocations/frees - Valgrind should be able to do it.

Comment: thanks for the answer.I have one more question.if i wanted to allocate memory for a 2d array using a void function, would this be correct?

void allocate2D(int*** Array, int rows){
*Array =malloc( rows*sizeof( int * ) );
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  (*Array)[i] = malloc( rows*sizeof( int ) );
 }
}

Comment: @CpZNick That seems correct, although you might want to also specify columns.